# How to fetch nodes (required nodes) associated to a node (criteria) based on a specific property of the node (criteria node) in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am very new to Neo4j, I just started working on it. I have been through the basic tutorials about neo4j and have got quite a hang of the Cypher Query Language. However I am stuck at a particular query.

I have a structure as `A-[relX]->B-[relY]->C-[relZ]->D` where A, B, C, D are all labels. Now I have a requirement where I want to find all the nodes of label A related to the node of label D for specific property of D.
Lets say

1. D:{name :"Tom"}
2. D:{name :"Dick"}
3. D:{name :"Harry"}

are my nodes f label D and I want to find all A's connected to D:{name :"Harry"} i.e, where name = "harry" for label D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be pretty straightforward.  If you just want the ones related to "Harry":

```
MATCH (a:A)-[:relX]->(:B)-[:relY]->(:C)-[:relZ]->(:D {name: 'Harry'})
RETURN a
```

If you want to match a number of names and return all of the `a`s:

```
MATCH (a:A)-[:relX]->(:B)-[:relY]->(:C)-[:relZ]->(d:D)
WHERE d.name IN ['Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry']
RETURN a
```

You might also want to know what `D` name was matched for each `a`:

```
MATCH (a:A)-[:relX]->(:B)-[:relY]->(:C)-[:relZ]->(d:D)
WHERE d.name IN ['Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry']
RETURN d.name, a
```

To return the information a bit more efficiently you could make the set of `a` nodes found for each name be an array:

```
MATCH (a:A)-[:relX]->(:B)-[:relY]->(:C)-[:relZ]->(d:D)
WHERE d.name IN ['Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry']
RETURN d.name, collect(a)
```

Lastly, as a style tip, I generally try to put the "anchor" node (one of the nodes that has a condition on it) at the start.  That would look like:

```
MATCH (d:D)<-[:relZ]-(:C)<-[:relY]-(:B)<-[:relX]-(a:A)
WHERE d.name IN ['Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry']
RETURN d.name, collect(a)
```

For more Cypher style tips, see Nigel Small's [The Zen of Cypher](https://web.archive.org/web/20160314013101/http://nigelsmall.com/zen)